# How do I create full width video Carousel in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: video, header, bootstrap-4, carousel

I am creating a portfolio website, and I want to create a full width video Carousel for the home page using Bootstrap4. I have researched how to create it the right way, but I am still having trouble. Currently, the first slide has a video, but it displays the controls, and does not replay once it ends. I would like to have it go to the next slide once the video on that slide ends. I have images in the second two slides currently. When I try to put in a video file in those slides, it will not show up on preview. How would you code this? Any help will be appreciated ! Thanks!

Below is my current code for carousel:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data- 
    ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" 
    class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- First Slide -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" 
     src="video/jzportfolioheader1.mp4" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
     </div>
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
     <h2>Hi, I'm John.</h2>
     <p>I'm a Junior Web Developer</p>
     </div>
     </div>
    
     <!-- Second Slide -->
     <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/jzportfolio2.png" 
     alt="Second slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
     <h2>Adobe Creative Cloud - Design</h2>
     <p>I use Adobe Photoshop, Illustrator, inDesign, After Effects, 
      Premiere Pro, and Animate to design cool websites.</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">More 
     Info</button>      
     </div>
     </div>
    
     <!-- Third Slide -->
     <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/jzportfolio1.png" 
     alt="Third slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h2>Web Dev Tools</h2>
        <p>I use HTML5, CSS3, Javascript, Wordpress, Bootstrap 4.0, 
     jQuery, and Adobe Dreamweaver to develop amazing websites.</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">More 
     Info</button>  
     </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" 
     role="button" data-slide="prev">
     <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
     </a>
     <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" 
     role="button" data-slide="next">
     <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
     </a>
     </div>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
      <script       src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js">       </script>
```

Comment: *"I would like to have it go to the next slide once the video on that slide ends"* -- where is the code you've attempted for this? Do you have some video callback function?

Comment: I have not wrote code for that yet. At this point, I am just trying to the controls hidden.